# How to plot selection over time for only components, but not magnitute. of a vector in paraview?

Tags: plotting, paraview

I am doing a time evolution analysis for a structure and have already got the displacement result, which is a vector including x and y components. And I want to plot the time evolution of x and y displacement respectively for a point in the structure. But every time I use plot selection over time, it shows the evolution of displacement magnitute.

How can I get the single component evolution?
In addition, it seems that the magnitute plot does not include signs (all of them are positive), am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magnitude plot may display the norm of the vector so it is obviously non-negative.

You may be able to get what you are looking for by taking the dot product of your vector with the vectors from the canonical base. If your data is a vector $\vec{u}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ then you can recover the x component by taking
$\vec{u} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$

You should be able to do that with the calculator (see Filters) and the buttons iHat, jHat.